# Sql 2 primary keys remove rows where 1 primary key is duplicated

Tags: sql, duplicates, mariadb, primary-key, sql-delete

I ve a Sql table (mariaDB) with 2 Primary keys. I want to remove the rows where the first primary key is duplicated.(yes i know that primary keys cant be duplicated but with 2 Primary keys they work like a touple so that it is possible, but in my case not wanted) example:

| id(pk) | name(pk) | smth | smth else |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1234 | qwerty |
| 1 | b | 4567 | asdf |

and i want to remove the 2nd line cause the id key is duplicated.

tried:
almost any delete query with row count
the query i tried last:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS RN
FROM product_names
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1
```

Comment: You probably mean you have a 2 column pk.

Comment: Order by name not id. Order by id doesn’t give you a definitive order. How do you identify the specific line you want to keep when ids are duplicated?  Order is not guaranteed in a db. So we need a way to identify what record to keep or get rid of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify the definition, you cannot have two primary key in a table. But the primary key of your table is composed of two columns.

To improve your schema, you may want to alter your table so that the primary key is only based on first column. However, depending on the database engine, it can be usefule to keep your composite key. It may speed up query which retrieve the second column only from the primary key. In that case you may want to add a unique clause to the first colume of your primary key.

To cleanup your table you can use that, but beware it doesn't have a filter on the second column, meaning any column with the same id can be deleted depending on its order.

```sql
WITH duplicated AS (
    SELECT id, name, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a) row_number
    FROM product_names
    ORDER BY name
)
DELETE FROM product_names
WHERE (a, b) IN (SELECT a, b FROM duplicated WHERE row_number > 1);
```